# DirectX 11 feature levels

Tags: directx-9, directx-11

I've written a program, which uses DirectX 11. When creating the device, I use feature level  9.0c (D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3, to be specific).

My initial understanding of feature levels is, that choosing one allows the program to be compatible with graphics cards, which does not support later versions of DirectX.

As far as I know, DirectX 11 may not be installed on Windows Vista (at least not officially), but imagine, how surprised I was, when all graphics features worked like charm on Windows Vista.

The question is: why? How? Is the DirectX 11 so smart, that it uses DirectX 9 binaries, when no 11 ones are available? Is it maybe the feature of DirectX 10? Maybe Microsoft enabled Vista support for DirectX 11? There must be something to it, I don't believe in such coincidences...

MSDN is silent on this matter. Or at least I couldn't find the appropriate topic.

Any explanation for this?

Comment: I may post the link to my program if you wish, such that you may test it yourself on Vista or XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install SP2 or KB971512 on Visa then it supports DirectX 11: http://www.mydigitallife.info/directx-11-direct3d-for-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008-free-download/